# iOS UI Unknown width/height ImageView and unknown sized label under it

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an iOS app that reads image and a text from my API and put each item in it's UITableView cell.

My goal is to make the image to fit the user screen (with a little margin of few pixels in the corner, just like Instagram) and a text below it.

I actually did that, but the text is not always below the image and sometimes it gets INSIDE the imageview, for a reason I don't know. This is my work so far:

[My Custom Table cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnWze.png)

So.. What are my problems?

- The text sometimes getting cut by the image: [Text is cut in the image bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GipMp.png). **how do I fix that?**
- The text is limited to few lines, when the text is bigger than the fixed width I provided, it just not showing any more text.
  I need to show all of the text; sometimes its just one line, sometimes it's 10 lines. **How do I do that?**

Hope that you can help me,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem. I think the issue is that there arnt constraints on the imageview size and the label size (as a result the imageview probably expands to the largest possible size.)

For the second issue, one of the following must be dynamic, image size or cell size. Im thinking your image sizes are gonna be fixed, so you should probably look into dynamic cell heights

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Auto layout ?
If yes then you can specify top-left,width and aspect ratio based on that
for the label you can specify the top constraint

I have the same design like Instagram image and this worked for me

If not using autolayout you may have to set the label frame programmatically

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? I'm iOS beginner and I didn't understand much of your answer \: